# Is #k-XORSAT #P-complete?

Tags: computational-complexity

k-XORSAT is the problem of deciding whether a Boolean formula $$\bigwedge_{i \in I} \oplus_{j=1}^k l_{s_{ij}}$$ is satisfiable.  Here $\oplus$ denotes the binary [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor) operation, $I$ is some index set, and each clause has $k$ distinct literals $l_{s_{ij}}$ each of which is either a variable $x_{s_{ij}}$ or its negation.

Equivalently, $k$-XORSAT requires deciding whether a set of linear equations, each of the form $\sum_{j=1}^k x_{s_{ij}}\equiv 1\; (\mod 2)$, has a solution over $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Every decision problem Q has an associated counting problem #Q, which (informally speaking) requires establishing the number of distinct solutions.  Such counting problems form the complexity class [#P](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Complexity_Zoo%3ASymbols#sharpp).  The "hardest" problems in #P are #P-complete, as any problem in #P can be reduced to a #P-complete problem.

The counting problem associated with any NP-complete decision problem is #P-complete.  However, many "easy" decision problems (some even solvable in linear time) also lead to #P-complete counting problems.  For instance, Leslie Valiant's original 1979 paper [*The Complexity of Computing the Permanent*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975%2879%2990044-6) shows that computing the permanent of a 0-1 matrix is #P-complete.  As a second example, the list of #P-complete problems in the companion paper [*The Complexity of Enumeration and Reliability Problems*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0208032) includes #MONOTONE 2-SAT; this problem requires counting the number of solutions to Boolean formulas in conjunctive normal form, where each clause has two variables and no negated variables are allowed.  (MONOTONE 2-SAT is of course rather trivial as a decision problem.)

Andrea Montanari has written about the partition function of $k$-XORSAT in some [lecture notes](http://www.stanford.edu/~montanar/TEACHING/Stat316/handouts/lecture-4.pdf), and his book with Marc Mézard apparently discusses this (unfortunately I do not have a copy available to hand, and the relevant Chapter 17 is not included in Montanari's online draft).

These considerations lead to the following question:

> Is #$k$-XORSAT #P-complete?

Note that the formula in Montanari's notes does not obviously appear to answer this question.  Just because there is a nice closed form solution, doesn't mean we can evaluate it efficiently: consider the [Tutte polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial).

Some difficult counting problems in #P can still be approximated in a certain sense, by means of a scheme called an FPRAS.  Jerrum, Sinclair, and collaborators have linked the existence of an FPRAS for #P problems to the question of whether $NP = RP$.  I would therefore also be interested in the subsidiary question

> Does #$k$-XORSAT have an FPRAS?

*Edit: clarified second question as per comment by Tsuyoshi Ito.  Note that Peter Shor's answer renders this part of the question moot.*

Comment: Note that some #P-complete problems (e.g. the DNF counting problem) have an FPRAS.  Therefore, the #P-completeness does not rule out the existence of an FPRAS.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting this, have edited the question so it makes more sense.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The solutions for XOR-SAT form an affine subspace of the vector space GF(2)$^n$. You can see this by realizing that if you add three solutions together, you get another solution. The counting problem for XOR-SAT is then that of deciding how many points are in this affine space over GF(2). This is trivial if you know the rank of a generating matrix for this space (the number is $2^r$ for rank $r$). This rank can be figured out by a standard linear algebra algorithm, so the counting problem is in polynomial time.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but does this immediately imply that k-XORSAT is not #P-complete?

Comment: The way I understand Peter's answer, yes: compute the rank $r$ of the system, then the answer is $2^r$.  As the rank is at most $k$, a constant, this can be computed in polynomial time.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Peter’s answer explains how to compute the number of the solutions to any given instance of the XORSAT problem in polynomial time (and k-XORSAT is a special case of XORSAT).  Therefore, yes, it implies that the counting version of k-XORSAT is not #P-complete — unless the whole #P is computable in polynomial time!

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I was confused by the remark about problems solvable in linear time leading to #P-complete problems, but now I see that the remark was about problems whose decision versions are solvable in linear time and whose counting versions are #P-complete.

Comment: I'll edit the question to remove this source of confusion.

Answer (score 4):

FYI: In our book we explain that the number of solutions of $Ax=b$ is $2^{n-rank(A)}$ as mentioned by Peter.